# Looking for EMS emulators that work on XT machines

Tags: ram

EMS memory can be used to make UMB because it's mapped to upper memory as page frames. Quarterdeck QRAM(QRAM.SYS) is a driver that changes page frames to UMB. Therefore, UMB can be created by combining EMS card and QRAM.

Here is the CONFIG.SYS I'm actually using to create UMB on an XT machine:

```
DEVICE=REMM.SYS
DEVICE=QRAM.SYS r:1
DEVICE=DOSMAX.EXE /R+ /N+ /P-
```

- REMM.SYS: an EMS card driver for AST SixPak Premium
- QRAM.SYS: changes EMS page frames to UMB
- DOSMAX.EXE: moves DOS system data to UMB

Some EMS emulators use hard disk to create EMS memory. If a suitable EMS emulator exists, it will be possible to create UMB on an XT machine without EMS card. I found three utilities:

**1. Above Disk**

[image: Above Disk Image 1]
[image: Above Diks Image 2]
[image: Above Disk Image 3]
[image: Above Disk Image 4]

(The images above were taken from virtual box, but they look exactly like the screen my real XT shows except of the part 'Extended Memory'.)

It makes EMS memory by using hard disk, and works on XT machines. The EMS memory is mapped to upper memory. But Above Disk needs both CONFIG.SYS and AUTOEXEC.BAT to work. Therefore, QRAM cannot be used with Above Disk because it can be used only in CONFIG.SYS.

**2. VMS40**

It makes EMS memory by using hard disk, and works on XT machines, and needs CONFIG.SYS only to work. But the EMS memory is not mapped to upper memory. Therefore, QRAM cannot be used with VMS40 because it needs page frames mapped to upper memory.

**3. Turbo EMS**

It didn't work.

I know that EMS memory emulated by using hard disk is very slow. However, it helps to free up XT's base memory when used with QRAM. Please let me know if you know any other EMS emulators that work on XT.

Comment: How is your VirtualBox VM configured, and what EMSDRVR is that?

Comment: Your reasoning is undermined by this problem: page frames and the memory mapping that uses them rely on processor features that simply *don't exist* on 8086/88, 80186, or 80286. They appeared at the 80386. By the time the ability to use UMBs appeared in DOS, 8086/88 hardware was completely obsolete. Nobody tried to make those features work on XT-class hardware, because it was pointless.

Comment: @Justme Virtual Box VM was only used for the convenience of taking images. In the given images, the behavior of Above Disk is the same both in VM and in real XT. EMSDRVR is a device driver of Above Disk.

Comment: @Sung Yes but did you select a 8086 or 8088 as CPU? How much memory you gave to the VM? Memory managers can work differently on different CPUs. And if your VM provides UMBs then the EMS driver can use it as page frame.

Comment: @Justme You were right! A while ago I was taking pictures of my real XT. The Above Disk's screen shown in VM is the same as that of the real XT, as I said in my post. But that was a "misrepresentation" of Above Disk and MSD. They reported that the EMS memory was mapped to E000 in the upper memory, but testing on my real XT with some utils that use EMS, such as Cshow and Mod Master XT, has shown that to be a lie. No software EMS emulator that can use memory past 640KB will work on an XT.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No software EMS emulator that can use memory past 640KB will work on an XT, unless there is some hardware thing that already provides memory in the UMB which the EMS can then use as a page frame for disk swapping.

But no piece of software can emulate memory in the UMB area.

Which is why at least a 386 is needed to run the DOS under virtual 86 mode for emulating EMS.

On an XT, you need real hardware which provides memory in the UMB area. Either provided by an add-on card, or support from motherboard chipset.

If there is nothing that provides memory in UMB, then
software EMS that swaps to disk can only use the conventional memory area for the page frame, so it takes away 64KB from the 640KB you might have.

Comment: Above Disk and VMS40 that I mentioned work on XT. They seem to work in real mode.

Comment: @Sung you wanted EMS in UMB. You can't emulate a page frame in UMB with XT. Above Disk will take 64KB of conventional memory and uses that as page frame. QRAM should be no different on an XT.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know how Above Disk works, it seems to take 17KB (EMSDRVR + ABOVE) of conventional memory.

Comment: It might be useful to clarify that RAM must be present in the UMB, but the board that provides it need not be designed for EMS.  If e.g. one has a motherboard with 256KB, and a board that can hold 576KB (intended to upgrade a 64KB machine to 640K) it may be practical to rewire the board so that 192K of its memory is above the 640K mark.  Depending upon the design of the board, this may be possible merely by moving "suitcase" jumpers, or may require adding additional wires, maybe cutting traces, and possibly adding a component like a 74LS00 (a cheap period-aprpopriate part).

Comment: Hmm, anyway, if the motherboard already provides the extra memory as UMB, then it is possible for EMS emulator to use the existing UMB area for disk-swapping EMS emulation. But no software can provide UMBs virtually.

Comment: PC-Speed emulator (V30) on Atari ST is able to emulate EMS in emulation mode. This is due to the fact that the whole address range of the V30 is mapped inside 1 MiB of the 68000. What is a memory hole on a real XT is real memory in PC-Speed. This allows, if the host has enough memory (2MiB mini) to get 704 KiB DOS memory, UMB blocks and an EMS window into the host memory (a driver exists that calls the 68000 to copy pages into the EMS pages).

Answer (score 6):

### TL;DR:

No, it is not possible to emulate EMS/UMB on an XT class PC.

Any kind of virtual mapping needs a CPU supporting paged virtual memory, in other words, a 386 or above.

---

### Details:

#### The Real Stuff:

DOS needs hardware to provide memory within it's address space. For UMB this memory needs to be presented within the [Upper Memory Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_memory_area#UMB), that is above 640 Ki. For XT class machines this was achieved by one of several ways:

- Basic memory expansion cards, as needed to expand the original PC beyond 64 or 256 Ki, with changed decoding for address space above 0A0000h. Either by modifying genuine IBM cards or cards made to include such address spaces.
- Memory provided by cards made for [Expanded Memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expanded_memory) (EMS). EMS was introduced as a way to have more data RAM resident by banking memory into a 64 KiB block in UMA. Some of these cards as allowed as well to put memory into any memory location and more than 64 Ki at a time.
- Late XT clone boards were build using megabit RAM for cost reduction. This  resulted in 768 KiB or 1 MiB of installed memory. Some XT chipsets allowed to map the additional RAM (past 640 Ki) to fill up UMA.

All of these solutions allowed the use of UMB, all with rather simple drivers - usually just adding the additional memory to the MS-DOS memory management. Most important: **All of them need real hardware to put memory at those locations.** And there came ...

#### Virtual Games:

The 80386 brought an integrated paged memory management unit, offering another way: Remapping of memory using virtual memory. And that's what EMS 'Emulators' do. They map memory from "outside" DOS' 1 Mi address space into that.

#### Hard, But No Disk

While being called virtual, this is *still based on real memory,* only visible to DOS at a different address than external hardware sees it. This of course implies that there is no way to use a hard disk to fill up that memory (*1).

---

### Bottom Line:

***DOS can use UMB only if real memory is present in UMA***

An XT class (8086/88) machine can in no way use any virtual memory mechanics for UMB.

---

*1 - Well, one could of course think of some kind of software based EMS emulation, but that would still require real hardware UMA memory to exist prior. Doing so would be not only incredible slow - as each page change would require a disk write of the old page (there is no dirty bit to avoid that) before the new is read, but also only compatible with well behaving software.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. It was very helpful for me.

Comment: PC-Speed on Atari ST was a XT class that could do it but that was a strange XT which could use the 68000 of the host to access to more memory, RAM-Disk, EMS etc. I loved it and 1989 I could not afford to buy an XT even if 386 were already available, but thanks to this cheap extension of my Mega ST2 I could keep up with the requirements of my studies at University (besides ST software that no PC was able to reach (Signum!, etc).

Comment: @PatrickSchlüter I would believe using PC-Speed and a 'second CPU' does qualify as dedicated hardware to support UMA, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Raffzahn never said it wasn't. Just wanted to give an example of an exotic XT class PC with UMA.